# Change default path mozilla thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

tengo una duda, hace poco instale mozilla thunderbird en ubuntu 12.04
pero me gustaria cambiar la ruta por defecto donde este cliente descargar los  mensajes.
Por ejemplo yo cambie la ruta en el outlook (*.pst) estan ubicados en el disco D, 
algo parecido quiero hacer para mozilla thunderbird. Gracias.

Hello I am Peruvian, I have a question, I recently installed mozilla thunderbird in Ubuntu 12.04 but I would like to change the default path where this client to download messages. 
For example, I change the path in Outlook (*. Pst) are located in the disk D, something I do to mozilla thunderbird. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Edit - Account Settings - Server Settings and set "Local directory" (using the Browse button) to your folder of choice.